# Defining "All other Values" in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, calculate-values

I am trying to use the "Сategorized symbology" in QGIS. I am having a problem because some of the data I need seems to be in the "all other values" category when categorized.

Is there a way to define the values in "all other values" or predefined that I want all values to be shown as separate categories?

Comment: How did it happen ? did you add new value after setting the categorized symbology or are those null value ? did you try to add the missing categories (by clicking on the "+" button) ?

Comment: Are you using an expression to categorize your symbology? if so, please provide the expression and the data or a subset of the data representing the issue so we can help you. As the question stands it is not possible to answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Rule Based Symbology to define rules to your categories and a "ELSE" rule to all another.

[image: RULE-BASED SIMBOLOGY]